# OpenGL ES 2.0. Color blending and incorrect rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, blending

Sometimes a part of screen isn't displayed like on screenshots below (wrong):
[real device wrong, emulator wrong, emulator right](https://copy.com/lyZqP48ysAeRYKHL/3in1.png), 
sometimes this render is wrong like on screenshot of Genymotion emulator (wrong).
It rarely happens and I can not find the source of the problem.
If I disable blending, I can not reproduce the error. Perhaps, this trouble is related to something more depth and mixing colors is only "the last straw".

I use setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY), and of course, this happens when render pause.

EGLconfig:

```java
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
}
```

GLSurfaceView.Renderer:

```java
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.08f, 0.12f, 0.16f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthRangef(0.f, 1.f);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);

    int i, j;
    GLES20.glUseProgram(prg_shaderCube);

    //  GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ZERO);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            flat = pattern[i][j];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMirrorFlankWithClippingMVP, 0, mMirrorFlankDownVPWithClippingMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_changematrixCube, 1, false, mMirrorFlankWithClippingMVP, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixCube, 1, false, mModelMatrix, 0);
            drawFlat(flat);
        }
    }
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_ALWAYS);

    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(prg_shaderChess);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixBoard, 1, false, mMirrorChessMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[4]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_chess);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_chess);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_position_chess, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_CHESSBOARD, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_color_chess, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_CHESSBOARD, 12);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_FRONT);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[4]);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, capacityChessInd, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_chess);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_chess);
    //   GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ZERO);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(prg_shaderCube);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            flat = pattern[i][j];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMirrorFlankMVP, 0, mMirrorFlankViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_changematrixCube, 1, false, mMirrorFlankMVP, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixCube, 1, false, mModelMatrix, 0);
            drawFlat(flat);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            flat = pattern[i][j];
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMirrorDownMVP, 0, mMirrorDownViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixCube, 1, false, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_changematrixCube, 1, false, mMirrorDownMVP, 0);
            drawFlat(flat);
        }
    }

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVP, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixCube, 1, false, mModelMatrix, 0);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_changematrixCube, 1, false, mMVP, 0);
            drawFlat(flat);
        }
    }

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(prg_shaderChess);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[4]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_chess);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_chess);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_position_chess, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_CHESSBOARD, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_color_chess, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_CHESSBOARD, 12);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[4]);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(u_modelmatrixBoard, 1, false, mViewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, capacityChessInd, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_chess);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_chess);

}

 private void drawFlat(int flat) {
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[flat]);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_cube);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_cube);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_normal_cube);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_position_cube, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_FLAT, 0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_color_cube, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_FLAT, 12);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(attr_normal_cube, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE_IN_FLAT, 24);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo[flat]);
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, capacityFlatInd[flat], GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_position_cube);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_color_cube);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(attr_normal_cube);
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: this might not fix your problem. But don't we also have to clear the depth buffer like `GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` ?

Comment: @Kiran I clean buffers separately in different parts of the program, please see the code.

Comment: ok. sorry. i missed it.

Comment: I think @Kiran's concern is valid. It looks like for the first parts of the rendering you use the depth buffer, before you clear it. So at that point, I believe the content of the depth buffer is undefined. Or am I missing something you're doing to get the depth buffer initialized?

Comment: @Reto  I can clean the depth buffer in any place where I need to, and more than once. This is not a problem and this even reduces the fps. Rendering is done correctly, it can be seen from the figure.
To render objects of the part before "GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);" I use the [modified matrices][1] for clipping, so these objects are located closer on the axis Z than objects are drawn later.
Z-values of farther objects will override at the next passage of the frame. There is no need to clear the buffer at the beginning.  [1]:   http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-Oblique.pdf

Comment: Sure, you can clear the depth buffer whenever you want/need to. But as far as I can tell, you have the depth test enabled when you start drawing, with the content of the depth buffer undefined. If that's the case, the result of the depth test is undefined.

Comment: The depth buffer cannot be undefined, it is filled with 0 depth for each pixel by default. Sorry, I don't understand. I added a clearing to start of frame but this has not influenced a render.